# Why is Gnome Shell sending data over my wireless network?

Tags: networking, wifi, gnome3, fedora

I have been checking which processes under my Fedora Linux 18 are using my upload bandwidth and I occasionally see that Gnome Shell is one of them. Why should it be sending data over my wireless network?

Comment: I have no answer for this - just a suggestion: Why don't you fire up `wireshark` and check out the traffic it transmits?

Comment: Yeah, I might try that if no reason is found :-)

Answer (score 0):

Install `iptraf-ng` to see which TCP/UDP connection eats your bandwidth:

```
sudo yum install iptraf-ng
```

Then use `netstat -anp` to find which process starts TCP connection(s) that you dislike.

Finally, kill them all.